# common constant variables in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

Where is the best place to create a class that contain all the application constant variables ?

is it :
- **Bootstrap** 
- **In the Application Common library**

for example :
1- When i retrieve an image name from a database if this record doesnt have an image , i want to put a default value somewhere so i can use it in my models

** a constants that i use in all my application so if i change it , i dont want to go back to all in my code and change it everywhere

Comment: Could you explain why do you want to use them? Why do you prefer using constants instead of storing the config object in the registry for example?

Comment: Ok sure, i will edit my question now

Comment: I think using global constants is a little against common design patterns and modern coding. I think you'd better use a Zend_Config object in global scope with Zend_Registry or populate these default image value's from your models looks like the right solution in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

application.ini is the best place for example define some constant there

```
constants.PUBLIC_PATH =  APPLICATION_PATH "/../public/"
constants.THEME = blue
```

Then in your bootstrap do

```
protected function setConstants($constants)
{
    foreach($constants as $name => $value)
    {
         if(!defined($name))
            define($name, $value);
    }

}
```

ZF take 'constants' from config and call setConstants method in your bootstrap passing all lines prefixed by constants hence its an array .

Comment: How i can Call them from my controller ?

Comment: you call them same way as you call any constant created with define() method use PUBLIC_PATH , THEME as it anywhere including controller.

Answer (score 1):

I try not use constants and prefer class constants over global constants. However, when constants are unavoidable, for whatever reason, I go with .ini config file and Bootstrap/library/model class constants.

### An example of .ini config constants

*(assumes [default zf project structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html))*

application/configs/application.ini

```
constants.MESSAGE_1 = "Message 1"
constants.MESSAGE_2 = "Message 2"
```

Bootstap.php

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initConstants()
    {
        $options = $this->getOption('constants');

        if (is_array($options)) {
            foreach($options as $key => $value) {
                if(!defined($key)) {
                    define($key, $value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Example usage in controller:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->message1 = MESSAGE_1;
        $this->view->message2 = MESSAGE_2;
    }
}
```

I would extend on the above to allow configuration of *how* your constants are defined. For example you may want all constants UPPERCASED or not, and allow or disallow already defined constants, so:

application/configs/application.ini

```
constants.forceUppercase = 1
constants.allowAlreadyDefined = 1
constants.set.message_1 = "Message 1"
constants.set.message_2 = "Message 2"
```

Bootstrap:

```
    protected function _initConstants()
    {
        $options = $this->getOption('constants');

        if (isset($options['set']) && is_array($options['set'])) {

            if (isset($options['forceUppercase'])
                && (bool) $options['forceUppercase']) {
                $options['set'] = array_change_key_case($options['set'], CASE_UPPER);
            }

            $allowAlreadyDefined = false;
            if (isset($options['allowAlreadyDefined'])
                && (bool) $options['allowAlreadyDefined']) {
                $allowAlreadyDefined = true;
            }

            foreach($options['set'] as $key => $value) {
                if (!defined($key)) {
                    define($key, $value);
                } elseif (!$allowAlreadyDefined) {
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                        "'%s' already defined!", $key));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

### Bootstrap class constants

Could be your own library, or model class, etc., it depends.

In the bootstrap:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    const MESSAGE_CONSTANT = "Hello World";

    // ...
}
```

Example usage in controller:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->message = Bootstrap::MESSAGE_CONSTANT;
    }
}
```